# Count all answers that are correct

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that will display a test name , the number of total answers.

How would I COUNT all the correct answers as well as CUA.

A correct answer is when ua.Answer_ID matches ca.Answer_ID

Comment: Do you have a question? (And see prepared statements in PHP's mysqli API)

Comment: @Strawberry do prepared statments works with fetch_arrays

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Sum(ua.Answer_ID =  ca.Answer_ID)

Comment: what does 'CUA' mean?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your query is wrong.. you are joining by the condition ca.Answer_ID = ua.Answer_ID so all the answer is only the correct answers... your Qcnt is actually what you asked us for.. I'll suggest adding a correlated query to count the QCNT like this:

```
SELECT ua.Test_ID  AS TID, ts.id, ts.Name, COUNT(*) AS CUA, ua.User_ID,
       (select count(*) from user_answers t where t.test_id = ua.test_id) as QCNT
FROM user_answers ua
INNER JOIN test_set ts ON ts.id = ua.Test_ID
INNER JOIN correct_answer ca ON ca.Answer_ID = ua.Answer_ID
WHERE ua.User_ID = '" . $userid . "' GROUP BY TID
```

Comment: The problem with this is that its messing with the QCNT . Its displaying the same as CUA

Comment: Hey , so i dont know what happened but the query stopped working

Comment: What is not working? @johnychew

Comment: well , the code above has stopped working . It doesnt display anything

Comment: That doesn't make sense , do you provide a good parameter to userid ? @JohnyChew .. Try this query : SELECT * FROM user_answers ua
INNER JOIN test_set ts ON ts.id = ua.Test_ID
INNER JOIN correct_answer ca ON ca.Answer_ID = ua.Answer_ID
WHERE ua.User_ID = '" . $userid . "'

Comment: if it doesn't return anything than you have a problem with your data, not the query.

Comment: how would that work, it doesnt include any TID,CUA or AUA.  I tried this code and the previous code in mysql and it just shows blank

Comment: Listen, the problem is with your data, something changed there.. maybe the conditions are not true anymore, or maybe there is not data anymore. But this query is fine

Comment: The data hasnt changed . I have noticed that the table must have allot of enteries for it to show anything

Comment: I have to answer a test 4 or 5 times for the table to get filled up before it shows anything